# Can an employee be fired for missing work during quarantine period required by company?

Tags: united-states, covid-19

Since the pandemic has started, my friend has missed work more than usual which has led to tension between them and their employer. For context, the business was recently acquired by a national corporation and is located in North Carolina.

The company has threatened to reduce the position to part time (with no benefits) or to outright fire my friend. Ordinarily this might be justified, but the kicker is that they required my friend to stay home and quarantine for 7 days, which added significantly to the total number of days missed recently. My friend also mentioned that not everyone in the workplace is being held to the same safety/quarantining standards. The manager (corporate hired) recently returned from a trip to Myrtle Beach and did not quarantine at all before returning to work. As North Carolina has no required quarantine period, there's no issue with the manager immediately returning, but requiring other employees to do so and then punishing them for it seems inappropriate.

Besides looking for a new job (which is difficult considering the current job climate), how should my friend handle this situation, and is termination on the grounds of missing too much time due to a quarantine even legal?

Comment: Why did they force him to stay home and quarantine? Just out of the blue by random chance? And what do you mean by "missed work more than usual"? Does he usually miss work?

Comment: My friend has a young child so 'more work than usual' with usual being the occasional sickness, etc. that would require a trip to the doctor and a day off. One of my friend's family members who often babysits returned from a trip out of state, which prompted the company to require my friend quarantine.

Comment: Do we know for certain that the 7 day quarantine period is the reason why your friend is facing this punishment?  Would he still be facing this predicament if that 7 days didn't happen?

Answer (score 2):

North Carolina is an at-will state, which means they can fire you for any (legal) reason or no reason at all.

There are states where what you do besides work is protected as long as it does not impact work, but since in your case it *does* impact work, I'm not going to look up if North Carolina has such rules.

The only leg to stand on legally speaking is if you could prove that you had to quarantine unfairly compared to your boss because you were discriminated against for being a protected class. Being the underling compared to the boss sadly is not a protected class. The company does not have to allow you the same benefits it allows your boss.

So is it fair? Probably not. Is your company legally required to be fair? No. They can just fire you. For no reason. Or for any other reason. Having had voluntary contact with someone in your spare time so you have to quarantine by their rules is not a protected class as far as I know. You could have chosen to *not* meet with that person and come to work instead. You did not.

Comment: [NC employment at will](https://www.labor.nc.gov/workplace-rights/employee-rights-regarding-time-worked-and-wages-earned/employment-will)

Comment: To be fair, if they chose not to leave their kid with their babysitter then “come to work instead” isn’t actually an option. That doesn’t change anything legally since an employer doesn’t have to accommodate a lack of child care but this was, “stay home and watch the kid” or “use the babysitter and self-quarantine”. Either way they were missing work.

Comment: @BSMP Picking another baby sitter or not seeing them after they return would have worked, too. After all the world did not collapse when the baby sitter was out of town either. If they were missing work before every time their one single babysitter was unavailable, I can see why the company wanted to get rid of them.